# Controls in MAUI.NET does not render controls properly, unless I resize the application

Tags: c#, user-interface, rendering, viewmodel, maui

**tl;dr;**

The problem:
**controls like Entry etc. are not rendered after the UI is redrawed** (user click some button -> command invoke -> VM changed -> UI changes). There is usually blank space of background on the place of invisible controls.

However after I change a Window application or maximize it or turn of maximalization or move it to other monitor - then they **suddenly appears** (most often).

Environment: I have a solution in **MAUI.NET**, following **MVVM** architecture and **ViewModel-First** strategy. I focus on **Windows** version currently.

**more details:**

1. One of the main Views has a XAML node:

`<views:TabView Grid.Row="2" BindingContext="{Binding SelectedTab}"/>`

- TabView has only the grid with one line:

`<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemsDataSelector}"/>`

- SelectedTab is a property in VM that is of type TabViewModel. It includes mainly a collection of "widgets":

`public ObservableCollection<WidgetBaseViewModel> Items { private set; get; }`

- WidgetBaseViewModel is a base for each ViewModel that serves INotifyProperty and so on

2. Sub-user defines the main View in xml file
3. There is parser in application that consume this xml and builds a ViewModels hierarchy, so it creates the TabViewModels with Items

- Items has VMs for all controls - usually simple like TextboxViewModel having one property string with get and set or SwitchViewModel having one boolean property, but could be more complex

4. For each ViewModel there is also DataTemplate like follows

   ```
   <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:TextboxViewModel" x:Key="TextboxDataTemplate">
       <Entry Text="{Binding Value}" IsEnabled="{Binding ReadWrite}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

- Then I did DataTemplatesSelector like follows:

```
    internal class ItemsDataSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public ItemsDataSelector()
        {
        }

        private const int phraseViewModelLength = 9; // rule: at the end of every ViewModel object there is always "ViewModel" !!!
        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            try
            {
                var itemViewModelName = item.GetType().Name;
                var itemName = itemViewModelName.Substring(0, itemViewModelName.Length - phraseViewModelLength);
                var dataTemplateName = $"{itemName}DataTemplate";

                if (App.Current.Resources.TryGetValue(dataTemplateName, out object dataTemplate) && dataTemplate is DataTemplate)
                    return dataTemplate as DataTemplate;
                else
                    return null;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                ObjectProvider.Get<NotificationsViewModel>().AddUserMessage(new(UserMessageTypes.FAIL, $"Error while selecting widget based on ViewModel. Exception message: {exception.Message}"));
                return default(DataTemplate);
            }
        }
    }
```

Some parts are more complicated, because there is also Region that groups few simple ViewModels but is not required to reproduction...

I tried to minimalize the information to required.
If anyone can point me to the phrase I can google or propose what could be wrong with in this situation I would be ery thankful. If you need more information or code then let me know. Surely I would deliver all required.

**EDIT**

Not sure exact fix, but it seems that most of these kind of wrong behaviour were gone after I changed panel to FlexLayout. It seems to be more powerful and handle changes in UI in a proper way, automatically. Maybe someone get this information helpful.

Comment: Like any complicated situation that does not work, what's needed is to identify exactly which detail causes the failure. I recommend starting with the simplest possible situation, and building up towards what you need. Get any single piece of your implementation to work, with everything else hardcoded. Add to it. When you find what addition causes it to stop working, then someone can likely spot the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sure, you suggested proper way. By the way I edited the answer in order to help someone perhaps.